# Two different id values for the same individuals in different datasets

Tags: r

I have two vectors of id values associated with two different datasets. The two vectors correspond to the same individuals, but the id vectors are unrelated (and there are multiple observations for each individual in each dataset). My goal is to merge them by id, but because the ids are different and they are different lengths there is no way to do that without matching on id. There's obviously a lot more data than what I included in the example.

```
a <- c(4033,4833,681,9567,6175,7112,3889,264,3918,7685)
b <- c(1,4,7,10,14,18,22,26,27,37)
```

So 4033 = 1; 4833 = 4...etc.

dummy dataset1:

```
id day y
1  1   10
1  2   4
1  3   2
4  1   9
4  2   10
4  3   6
```

dummy dataset2:

```
id   day y1
4033 1   100
4033 1   120
4033 2   150
4033 3   200
4833 1   120
4833 2   100
4833 2   50
4833 3   100 
4833 3   200
```

What I would like is an easy way to get:

dummy dataset1 output:

```
id day y  id.2
1  1   10 4033
1  2   4  4033
1  3   2  4033
4  1   9  4833
4  2   10 4833
4  3   6  4833
```

I'm trying a solution in a forloop like:

```
for (i in length(dataset)) {
  dataset$id[dataset[[1]] %in% int] <- int1
}
```

But that's not working correctly (probably for an obvious reason I'm missing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we have two vectors, we can easily create a match with a named vector in `base R`

```
df1$id.2 <- setNames(a, b)[as.character(df1$id)]
df1
#  id day  y id.2
#1  1   1 10 4033
#2  1   2  4 4033
#3  1   3  2 4033
#4  4   1  9 4833
#5  4   2 10 4833
#6  4   3  6 4833
```

---

Or another `base R` option is `match`

```
df1$id.2 <- a[match(df1$id, b)]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L), day = c(1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), y = c(10L, 4L, 2L, 9L, 10L, 6L)),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

df2 <- structure(list(id = c(4033L, 4033L, 4033L, 4033L, 4833L, 4833L, 
4833L, 4833L, 4833L), day = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L), y1 = c(100L, 120L, 150L, 200L, 120L, 100L, 50L, 100L, 200L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: example works perfectly. I hadn't known of setNames. when I run on my actual dataset (which is identical in form to the example) I'm catching all NA's in the id.2 column - no errors pop up.

Comment: @Mik Can you do `setNames(as.character(a), b)[as.character(df1$id)]`

Comment: @Mik  Or if you can `dput`  with an example, it would be easier to know the exact structurer

Comment: @Mik can you try the `match` `a[match(df1$id, b)]`

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to make a data.frame of the IDs and use `merge`.

```
datasetID <- data.frame(id = b, id.2 = a)
merge(dataset1,datasetID)
  id day  y    a
1  1   1 10 4033
2  1   2  4 4033
3  1   3  2 4033
4  4   1  9 4833
5  4   2 10 4833
6  4   3  6 4833
```

**Data**

```
a <- c(4033,4833,681,9567,6175,7112,3889,264,3918,7685)
b <- c(1,4,7,10,14,18,22,26,27,37)
dataset1 <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L), day = c(1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), y = c(10L, 4L, 2L, 9L, 10L, 6L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```